# Angular2 route import error

Tags: angular, importerror

I'm getting this error when importing the router to app.routing.ts. i have added "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1" to package.json

[import error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNPa2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reinstall the node modules and the IDE.

Comment: Yes thank you it worked, but you don't need to reinstall all node modules just delete the angular modules and reinstall by 'npm install'

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember run **npm install** in command line after you put "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1" to package.json.

Comment: Have you tried closing and restarting your editor after running npm install? I've found that some editors (especially vscode) tend to freak out a bit after changing anything in the node_modules folder

Comment: yes that worked thank you. i found out that the problem was with the visual code.